# Panorama control panning issue

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application that uses a Panorama control. There are three PanoramaItems within this control, one PanoramaItem contains a WrapPanel having buttons which on tapping Navigate to other page. While the other two PanoramaItems have templatized listboxes, such that on tapping a ListBoxItem Navigation happens.

Now the problem occurs while panning accross the PanoramItems. At times, a button/listboxitem wihtin the selected panorama item gets clicked while i try to pan across to another panorama item. This problem does not occur on Emulator, it just occurs on the device.

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure but my view is that this is mostly how fast post tap the mouse or the finger moves, which results in either a pan gesture or a click. trying to prevent click from happening so that the button doesn't respond can impact the item/button selection if that's what the user intends

also from a design stand point, you could leave some space between panorama item titles and the listbox inside it. this gives more space for user to touch and pan. mostly it would be expected that you would pan using the item title and touch at lower portions when trying to interact with the items there

Answer (score 1):

Use `Tap` event instead of `Click` in your lists. This should help significantly.

Comment: This is an OLD question, but I want to 2nd this guy's answer.  It happened to me in WP8.  I'm using MVVM Light and had actual buttons in my DataTemplate for a LongListSelector.  When panning, the buttons would get pressed.  However, I was using the Command property, not a Click event, to trigger my actions.  Found out if you use Blend and add a Behavior through the Assets/Behavior menu, you can then make the EventTrigger that Blend creates trigger on a Tap instead of the default Load.